# Está dando conflito em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um comando copiando o que digito em um input no outro, porém quando tem mais de um registro ele não realiza a função no primeiro input. Abaixo chegue o codigo:

```
<td>id<input name="id" id="id" type="number" value="1" /></td>
<td>temporada<input name="temporada" id="temporada" type="number" value="1" /></td>
<td>episodio<input name="episodio" id="episodio" type="number" value="2" /></td><br/>
<td>teste<input name="teste" id="teste" type="text" style="width:1000px;" /></td><br/>
<td>url<input name="url" id="url" type="url" value="http://google.com"/></td>

<script>
    window.oninput = function(event){
        var campo = event.target.id; // pega o id do campo que chamou o evento
        
        if(campo == "episodio"){
            document.querySelector('#teste').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url').value +'"}';
        } else if(campo == "temporada"){
            document.querySelector('#teste').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url').value +'"}';
        } else if(campo == "url") {
            document.querySelector('#teste').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url').value +'"}';
        }
    };
</script>




<td>id<input name="id1" id="id1" type="number" value="2" /></td>
<td>temporada<input name="temporada1" id="temporada1" type="number" value="1" /></td>
<td>episodio<input name="episodio1" id="episodio1" type="number" value="2" /></td><br/>
<td>teste<input name="teste1" id="teste1" type="text" style="width:1000px;" /></td><br/>
<td>url<input name="url1" id="url1" type="url" value="http://google.com"/></td>

<script>
    window.oninput = function(event){
        var campo1 = event.target.id; // pega o id do campo que chamou o evento
        
        if(campo1 == "episodio1"){
            document.querySelector('#teste1').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada1').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio1').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url1').value +'"}';
        } else if(campo1 == "temporada"){
            document.querySelector('#teste1').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada1').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio1').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url1').value +'"}';
        } else if(campo1 == "url") {
            document.querySelector('#teste1').value = '{"temporada":"'+ document.querySelector('#temporada1').value +'","episodio":"'+ document.querySelector('#episodio1').value +'","link":"'+ document.querySelector('#url1').value +'"}';
        }
    };
</script>
```

como posso corrigir este conflito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que você está usando um [GlobalEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) do `window` object, e você o associa uma função e logo após o muda para outra. Então logicamente ele só irá executar o valor que está nele que é a última.

Para poder lidar com Inputs deve mecher no evento associado á ele com [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers). E deveria ter utilizado outro seletor para agrupar o que você queria modificar com o querySelector..
**Sugiro que estude a base HTML e CSS melhor para depois começar a manipulá-los com JavaScript**

Comment: Na verdade eu estou fazendo uma configuração no wordpress, então eu gero automaticamente o input de acordo com que vai preenchendo, se não fosse no wordpress eu já teria criado ele por completo. Ai nesta situação eu peguei só o resumo.